# How to make a fixed amount on the x-axis, so that it shows future hours?

Tags: javascript, jquery, time, flot

The code I have processes the data perfectly from my XML file, no problem, however if there is only one hour of data available it stretches across the whole x-axis like so:

```
                                                        15:00
```

I would like to see a fixed amount on the x-axis so instead of just showing just `15:00` it shows future hours as well, regardless if data is available yet. For example:

```
15:00     16:00     17:00     18:00     19:00     20:00     21:00
```

My current configuration is as follows, but not sure how to make the above happen:

```
{   
    grid: {
        hoverable: false,
        clickable: false,
        borderWidth: 1
    },
    xaxis: {
        mode: "time",
        minTickSize: [1, "hour"],
        timeFormat: "%H:%M"
    },
    yaxis: {
        min: 20,
        max: 45
    },
    legend: {
        show: true,
        position: 'ne'
    },
    valueLabels: {
        show:true,
        showAsHtml: true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I handle this type of situation on the json data creation side. Not sure if there is a flot option to do something similar. By using null's as the data value for all the timestamps I expect.  If you have the first hour time you can just increment it by 60 * 60 * 1000  E.g.

```
"data": [
  [
    1362139200000,
    1.56
  ],
  [
    1362142800000,
    null
  ],
  [
    1362146400000,
    null
  ],
  [
    1362150000000,
    null
  ],
  [
    1362153600000,
    null
  ],
  [
    1362157200000,
    null
  ],
  etc.
```

]

Comment: Ah good idea - once I get on my work computer again on monday I'll give it a go and let you know if it works! :)